# SQL if or coelesce statement in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a `copy` column.  The `copy` column has two values: `base` and `override`.  I have a simple question.  I want to return all rows `where copy = 'override'` but if there are none, then return all rows.

My logic is this:  return all rows where copy is overrride. If there is none, then return all the rows, since the only rows left are the `base` rows.

I'm having a hard time figuring this out.  Can this be done in a single statement?
Thanks.

Comment: Instead of coelesce did you try CASE statement?

Comment: Please show the SQL statement you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE copy = 'override'
or(select count(*) from TABLE where copy = 'override') = 0
```

Its untested, so tell me if it works. The idea is to either select where copy = override, or > in case there are no override, the first condition will always be false, and it goes to the OR part and then ideally I tried to implement there something like 1=1, so all rows will be fetched

Comment: so your method implies that the OR statement shows priority to the first condition?

Comment: The first condition have the priority over the or statement

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT * 
FROM `YourTable` 
WHERE `copy` = (SELECT IF(
    (
        SELECT `copy`
        FROM `YourTable`
        WHERE `copy` = 'override'
        LIMIT 1) = "override", 
    'override',
    'base'
    ))
```